# IONIC 4: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage: (?)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi and thank you very much to all of you!

I'm having the followin error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage: (?).

I installed the NativeStorage plugin with:

- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage
- npm install @ionic-native/native-storage

Then I open the app.module.ts and it looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    NativeStorage,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

And my homepage it's like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the same error!!!

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u try re running ionic serve ? after adding dependency to app.module ?

Comment: I didn't... and after restarting it's working like a charm... thank you very much!

Comment: i am glad it worked. Usually changes in app.module doesn't reflect, so then have todo this..